# writing to a file using java and command prompt

Tags: java, command-prompt

when I run this command `ffmpeg -i "C:\user\test.wmv" >C:\user\test.wmv_info.txt 2>&1` from command prompt it works but when I try to the same from java file by calling the command prompt it executes all right but does not writes to the file.

Any idea why?

my java code is:

```
public void getInfoThroughCommandLine(String sourceFilePath) {
    try {

        String infoFile = sourceFilePath+"_info.txt";
        String command = "ffmpeg -i \""
                + sourceFilePath +"\" >"+infoFile+" 2>&1";

        // Execute the command
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start " + command);

        logger.info("Executing getInfoThroughCommandLine command: " + command);


                    // Read the response
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getInputStream()));
        BufferedReader error = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                p.getErrorStream()));

        // Parse the input stream
        String line = input.readLine();
        System.out.println("ffmpeg execution of: " + sourceFilePath);
        while (line != null) {
            System.out.println("\t***" + line);
            line = input.readLine();
        }

        // Parse the error stream
        line = error.readLine();
        System.out.println("Error Stream: " + sourceFilePath);
        while (line != null) {
                        //do somthing
                    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Give us some code, pls. There can be a gazillion reasons ...

Comment: Show us your Java line of code that tries to do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're using `getRuntime().exec()` to execute?

If so the `Process` object returned by it would be the one giving you access to in/out streams of the command you execute. Just read from it and write your own file.

**-- edit based on discussion via comments --**

start in `"cmd.exe /c start " + command` would start the program in a separate window, and I guess the streams of the process are attached to that window.

```
C:\Users\z000dgqd>start /?
Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.
........
```

Try removing it. I.e.

```
    // Change this:
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start " + command);
    // to this
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c " + command);
```

Comment: i cant do this as my cmd prompt gets closed as soon as the command is executed. I could probably do it if the cmd remains open.

Comment: Stream would have the data until you read (or discard/close) it. Google for an example, try it and then come back if you have problems.

Comment: I am doing this and it is returning empty string -

Comment: What is returning empty string? Post the code. I do hope you've removed the redirection from the command.

Comment: oh..i didnt remove the redirection..let me do that and see

Comment: I inspected the input.readLine(); and error.readLine() and they both are null.

Comment: Remove `start` from your command line. It starts the program in a separate shell and [I guess] attaches the streams to that shell. So change `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start " + command);` to: `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c " + command);`

Comment: if i remove the start from the command then it stops to work.

Comment: I got it working by -
String[] launch = { "ffmpeg", "-i", videoFile };
  Process ffmpeg = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(launch);

Answer (score 2):

The `>` and `2>&1` are shell operators that tells the shell to redirect the output of your command (`ffmpeg -i "C:\user\test.wmv"`) to a specific file (`C:\user\test.wmv_info.txt`).

Those operators do not work in Java, in Java, you have to explicitly take the standard output and standard error (via [Process#getInputStream()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getInputStream%28%29) and [Process#getErrorStream()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream%28%29) respectively - I know it seems backwards) and write the output of those streams to file yourself.

Comment: +1: A shell is more than just a console-based version of a Run... prompt.  It does more than just pass arguments to executables.

Answer (score 0):

Redirection is handled by the command shell -- i.e., by `CMD.EXE` -- and if you're just feeding the line above to `Runtime.exec()`, it won't be done. You can either arrange to have this command line send to `CMD.EXE` -- which is complicated to get right -- or you can do the redirection yourself in Java by reading the process output and error streams and storing the data to a file.

Comment: I am able to get this commandline to go to cmd.exe. It excutes the command as well, but just not able to write to the file. It even creates the file.

Comment: Your code is writing the output of CMD.EXE to the file, not the output of the program. Remove the CMD.EXE /c and just run the program directly, then leave the stream capture in.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could write that command out to a .bat file and run that? Not the cleanest solution but it might work.